# D3DKMTOpenAdapterFromDeviceName and DeviceName

Tags: c, winapi, device, guid, gdi

I'm looking for the way to communicate with display driver, and found this function, its a bit poorly documented in msdn. I need to use this, because it will return me the handle which later i can use to display the gpu load in my application. But there is a problem, what i did is i looked in my Device Manager, and copied the value of the "the path to the device instance" in my gpu properties. it looks like so:

```
PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_6798&SUBSYS_04481043&REV_00\4&72ACCB3&0&0008
```

Here is the example of `D3DKMTOpenAdapterFromDeviceName` which i found:

```
 D3DKMT_OPENADAPTERFROMDEVICENAME name = { _T("\\\\?\\pci#ven_10de&dev_0a2b&subsys_9072104d&rev_a2#4&12796cb&0&0008#{1ca05180-a699-450a-9a0c-de4fbe3ddd89}") };
   HMODULE hGdi32 = LoadLibrary(_T("gdi32.dll"));
   PD3DKMTOpenAdapterFromDeviceName D3DKMTOpenAdapterFromDeviceName = (PD3DKMTOpenAdapterFromDeviceName)GetProcAddress(hGdi32, "D3DKMTOpenAdapterFromDeviceName");
   NTSTATUS status = D3DKMTOpenAdapterFromDeviceName(&name);
```

In this example they have some GUID at the end of the device `#{1ca05180-a699-450a-9a0c-de4fbe3ddd89}`. So which GUID from the device manager properties of my GPU i should use? I tried to use like half of the GUIDS from my VideoCard properties in Device Manager and always get - `"STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER"`

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution to this?

Comment: @AddisonSchuhardt Look at mi answer :)

Answer (score 1):

`{1ca05180-a699-450a-9a0c-de4fbe3ddd89}` is the identifier of [GUID_DISPLAY_DEVICE_ARRIVAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/guid-display-device-arrival)

So you can compose your name like:

`"\\\\?\\" + deviceName + "#{1ca05180-a699-450a-9a0c-de4fbe3ddd89}"`

replacing your "\" for #; example with yours:

```
"\\\\?\\" + "PCI#VEN_1002&DEV_6798&SUBSYS_04481043&REV_00#4&72ACCB3&0&0008"+"#{1ca05180-a699-450a-9a0c-de4fbe3ddd89}"
```

And then to find this programatically you can do a COM search like this:

```
hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
        bstr_t("WQL"),
        bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_VideoController"),
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
        NULL,
        &pEnumerator);
```

And taking `PNPDeviceID` which is the string you've found at your Device Manager; take in account of being sure it's your currently in use graphic card, as it's possible to have more than one.